# Is my question doomed or can I still save it by rephrasing?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

Here's a question I asked recently:
[Does category theory help in operator algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467183/can-category-theory-make-the-trivial-trivially-trivial-in-operator-algebras)

So far I got 1 down vote and 4 close votes. Most of the close votes claim the question is unclear. Can somebody here help me understand what's unclear/wrong about it and how can i fix that if at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would help if you provided an example of a result that can be proven in both a "tricky" and "simple" way.

It would also help if you reduced the scope of the question.  At present, it seems like you're asking for someone to answer *every* question in elementary theory in terms of category theory.  You could, for example, ask for specific definitions and results that you'd want to see in these terms.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid your question touches on an unknown number of unknown unknowns. If you could reduce these in the favor of known unknowns, we could...

... What was the question again?

Comment: Haha I actually thought this was pretty funny. This illustrates the problem implicit in talking and/or writing in this way. While sometimes entertaining, this kind of writing ultimately obscures.